# How do define sequencing rules in imsmanifest file for SCORM 2004 2nd Edition

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

Everywhere I find example for the SCORM 2004 3rd Edition. Actually the LMS that we use only support 2nd Edition. Is there a place where I can find the sequencing tags to be defined in imsmanifest file for 2nd Edition. Or is there any difference at all between 2nd and 3rdEdition

Regards,
Lakshmi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing that 3rd Edition included that is not in 2nd Edition is a set of UI requirements for LMS's to implement. Most of stuff you see in 3rd Edition examples should apply to 2nd Edition as well, but in 2nd Edition you are going to see more implementation variation across LMS's.

Some helpful links:

You can find a high level overview of the differences between all SCORM versions [here](http://www.scorm.com/scorm-explained/business-of-scorm/scorm-versions/)

You can download the SCORM 2004 2nd Edition specs here.

You can also find a document providing a detailed listing of the changes between 2nd and 3rd Editions here. (look for the Impact Summary)

You can download manifest template files that are correct for each edition [here](http://www.scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/content-packaging/xml-schema-definition-files/).

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike. The second "here" is not linked. So I don't have to include any new xsd files for the difference in schema versions right? I just have to change the schema version tag in imsmanifest file to CAM 1.3 and no Run time API call changes and no sequencing tag definition changes? Mike, I would like to also thank you for the wonderful site scorm.com and the information that you have there for scorm learners. It has helped me a lot in developing my SCORM knowledge. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, that's not quite correct. The XSD files are slightly different between editions and should be changed. You are correct though that if you aren't using any of the functionality that changed between editions, you *shouldn't* have to change API calls or sequencing rules.

Comment: Tried to fix the "here" links, but for some reason the ADL site's link formats don't play well with StackOverflow. To get to them go to adlnet.gov, click on the links to download SCORM, and then use the breadcrumb at the top to get to "SCORM Documents", then "Previous Versions".